# Escaping strings containing single quotes in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell

How can i replace/escape the single quote in the name `cai.o'dowd` as its causing errors string is

```
i:0#.f|membership|cai.o'dowd_hod.com#ext#@xyz.onmicrosoft.com
```

Currently i'm doing the below and filtering based on userprinciplename

```
ObjectuserId = (Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq '$($User.LoginName.replace('i:0#.f|membership|',''))'").ObjectId
```

Any ideas how i can do this in PowerShell? I would also like to check if the field is null before processing it.

Comment: it does not sound right that a user principal has special characters like these. Is it possible to re-create the user? Also, do you think that  escaping a filter in the `Get-AzureADUser` is good question for a different forum?

Comment: Thanks but I can't change or recreate the name of the user. Which forum are you suggesting?.

Comment: Thanks Denis figured out
changes it to
 ObjectuserId = (Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq '$($User.LoginName.replace('i:0#.f|membership|','') -replace  "'", "''")'").ObjectId